# How to add Datetime Parameters in millisec to a HTTPPost of apache Httpclient jar in REST call

Tags: jakarta-ee, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am sending Datetime in millisec in HTTPPost, On the server side these dates appear to be invalid.So i had to append to the url itself  as work around and it worked.

```
        private HttpPost generateRequest() {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://XXXXXXXXX/myserverAPI");
    try {
        post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/json"));
        post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("appKey","xxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
        post.setParams(new Http);
        // Add additional header to getRequest which accepts application/xml data
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStart", "1548362234143"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeEnd", "1548364034143"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return post;
}
```

Now if I make these changes

```
HttpPost("https://XXXXXXXXX/myserverAPI?timeStart=1548362234143&timeEnd=1548364034143");
//post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
```

it works as expected.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the server at `https://XXXXXXXXX/myserverAPI` expecting you to post? Are you supposed to send it `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Even if you're not sure which it is, could you provide more information about the server side of this exchange?

Comment: No both application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded are not needed.It is a tomcat server.These are rest api's

Comment: Okay, what framework are you using on the server side of the REST APIs? Is it JAX-RS? Spring MVC? Straight servlets?

Comment: I am using a IOT framework called Thingworx , I am not sure what it is built on.It is deployed in tomcat as a webapp. I can a rest call to this application.